# create android circle fragment

Tags: android, view, fragment, android-custom-view

I want to have a circle fragment. I have searched and found out I should create a circle view. I have now created a view. If it's possible to do this way how can I add my fragment to a view? If it's not possible please help to create circle fragment.

Comment: What you want.. can you show the screen or ui ?

Answer (score 1):

circle.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="oval" >
        <gradient android:startColor="@color/yourColor" android:endColor="@color/yourColor"
            android:angle="270"/>
    </shape>
```

in fragment view

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/circle"/>
```